# GetSystemMetrics() reporting wrong mouse value on RDP session

Tags: c, windows, rdp

If I call the Windows GetSystemMetrics() function to learn about the number of buttons of the installed mouse but it always returns 2 if the function is called from a Remote Desktop session.

My company is working on a very long time development and, after migrating the application to 64bit, a strange issue related to the mouse buttons was detected when tested on a modern environment. The application needs 3 buttons to perform 3 different actions on graphic clients (ILOG IlView based).

However, the application only receives events for two buttons if executed on a Terminal Server/RDP session. But it works fine on a console session.

The software detects only two buttons and the graphic library ignores events coming from the third one.

The detection is internally made by invoking GetSystemMetrics() passing SM_CMOUSEBUTTONS as a parameter. The result varies between console and RDP sessions.

The problem seems to happen only if the session is executed on Windows 10, but not on Windows 7. No matter what Windows version is used on the client side.

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("Number of buttons: %d\n", GetSystemMetrics(SM_CMOUSEBUTTONS));

    return 0;
}
```

The expect result on Windows 10 on a RDP session is greater than 2 if a 3-button mouse is being used. The actual result is 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is workaround in ILOG(Views). You have to set UseRightButton=true in ini file
More details can be found on,
https://docs.roguewave.com/en/visualization/current/views/views.html#page/UserManuals/display.07.4.html#ww924027